# ¿Cómo surgió la expresión "tener potra"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, historia

En los diccionarios más antiguos (Nebrija, Casas, Covarrubias, etc) aparece definido **potra** únicamente como *hernia* (muchas veces especificando que es inguinal o escrotal). Por ejemplo, el Diccionario de Autoridades define:

> POTRA: Especie de hernia o rotura interior, que se causa por baxar las tripas à la bolsa de los testículos.

No es hasta la edición de 1803 cuando se añade una segunda entrada:

> POTRA. V. POTRO

En la edición de 1817 se añade

> CANTARLE A UNO LA POTRA: f. met. y fam. Sentir los quebrados algún dolor en la parte lastimada, lo que comúnmente sucede en la mudanza de tiempo.

A partir de la edición de 1852 se incluye (en la entrada potra = hernia, no en potra = yegua jóven)

> TENER POTRA. fr. fam. Ser dichoso.

que en la edición de 1950 recibe la acepción actual:

> **Tener potra** uno. fr. fig. y fam. Ser afortunado

¿Hay alguna explicación de esa aparición de "tener potra" tan diferente del significado de la palabra? Porque no creo que tener una hernia en el escroto sea ser dichoso o afortunado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Walen no anda desencaminado en su comentario. El tener una hernia en el escroto se ha asociado con tener una "ventaja especial" (en este caso una "habilidad especial" y por eso los que la tenían eran afortunados..

> Desde la antigüedad se decía que las personas con hernias tenían molestias que aumentaban con los cambios meteorológicos, debido a las variaciones de presión y humedad. **Así, aquellos con «potras» podían predecir lluvias y otro tipo de fenómenos meteorológicos, lo que se consideraba una suerte**.
>
> fuente: [lasprovincias.es](http://www.lasprovincias.es/culturas/201603/28/donde-viene-expresion-tener-20160328172829.html)

También lo encontramos en este otro blog

> En especial en la antigüedad, **el conocimiento de la predicción  de lluvias y demás inclemencias del tiempo era de gran valor**. **Aquéllos con "potras" tenían esta capacidad y se les consideraba afortunados por ello**. Por esa valía, comenzó a acuñarse dicha expresión que ha llegado a nuestros días con el significado conocido.
>
> fuente: [origendellenguaje](http://origenlenguaje.blogspot.com/2014/11/origen-de-la-expresion-tener-potra.html)

Lo dice también ["el listo que todo lo sabe"](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-proviene-utilizar-el-termino-potra-para-indicar-que-alguien-tiene-buena-suerte/)

> … El saberlo con suficiente anticipación ayudaba a que muchos agricultores pudiesen salvar sus cosechas.
>
> Así pues, a ese tipo de hernia (la potra) con el tiempo se le comenzó a considerar como algo bueno y de ahí que al que la padecía se le acabó considerando como alguien suertudo, dando lugar con los años a expresiones del tipo ‘menuda potra tiene’, ‘vaya potra he tenido’, ‘a ver si tenemos potra’…

Answer (score 0):

```
                          **PARTE I**
```

---

### ** El Potro, la hernia, la suerte y ¿Cómo surgió la expresión "Tener Potra"?**

**SÍNTESIS:**

**Potra** - Potra, del Francés "Poutre", palabra ya en desuso en esta lengua. En Español, por cambio semántico ó metonimia, "Tripa". Así tripa, intestino, vientre, abdomen, barriga, panza, potra...son todos sinónimos.

La palabra "Potra" se la relaciona con las *hernias* y con algo menos conocido, las *morcillas* por su forma curvada, ovalada, redondeada, alargada... y por ser ambas, a grosso modo, llamadas ó conocidas vulgarmente como "tripas", es decir, el lugar donde se encuentra el intestino y el nombre que recibe en general la forma cilíndrica u ovalada utilizada para procesar y embutir productos cárnicos de este género.

- En la obra de Tirso de Molina, "*El pretendiente al revés*", podemos encontrar una referencia a estas potras menos conocidas.
- Bien tu enfermedad quillotras. Lumbre hay.
- Vo a entrar en calor.
- ¡ Que mal tiempo para potras!.

Potras, en ese contexto en el que estaba lloviendo, significa "Morcillas", por su forma abultada y por ser las "tripas" el nombre que se le da al conjunto del alimento, normalmente, son de cerdo, carnero y vaca.
En este caso, al estar lloviendo, Mengo, indica que no es momento para hacer morcillas.

Por otro lado en el campo de la medicina, se dice que un médico es un mal cirujano cuando se le llama, "sacapotras", que viene a ser en la sabiduría popular un "sacamorcillas" o un "sacatripas" en sentido despectivo.

Igualmente para otros profesionales, se utiliza el término "sacamuelas", para un mal dentista.

Tener Potra es como decir "Tener Tripa", tener barriga, panza...

Antiguamente la vida dura que se llevaba en el campo, la escasez y el hambre en general hacia de aquellos que tenían potra, tripa, barriga, panza...se les vinculara con la salud, el bienestar y la felicidad o la fortuna de estar "preñada". De ahí la relación de "tener potra" con la de "tener buena suerte", pues se pensaba que los poseedores de estas "barriguitas/potras" poseían una buena dicha.

La relajación de costumbres, la revolución industrial y el cambio en los modos de vida en las personas, hizo que el concepto fuera reinterpretándose y adaptándose hasta la actualidad.

Hoy para referimos a ese tipo de vida o circunstancias decimos "Tener la curva de la felicidad", tener tripa, estar o ponerse como un tonelete, barriga cervecera ó si concurren otras eventualidades, "estado de buena esperanza".

Aunque en la actualidad, el sentido original y general que de la salud se tenía por aquel tiempo lejano, se ha perdido. Así "tener potra" ó "tener la curva de la felicidad", no es sinónimo de bienestar, suerte ó salud, aunque aún continua siendo válida en el caso de estar en estado gestante.

Diego M.

---

```
                                 I PARTE
```

---

Para aquellos que estén más interesados en las explicaciones, este es un resumen de la primera parte del proceso de estudio y como fue posible encontrar una respuesta adecuada, aunque por su longitud, primero tendría que escribir las anotaciones en alguna especie de trabajo previo, ya que aquí entiendo no es el lugar más apropiado para realizarlo y pido disculpas. No obstante la síntesis se puede leerla más arriba.

Primeramente dividiré en partes el esquema principal y en función del interés suscitado iré comunicando las partes siguientes.

La complejidad de algunas palabras no suele explicarse en una decena de líneas, o al menos, es lo que he tenido siempre presente, así, cuando se llega a la comprensión de un término, su sentido original en muchas ocasiones apenas guarda relación con el que se utiliza en la actualidad. Por el camino las ideas y las voces comienzan a relacionarse con otras y tanto la palabra original como su significado se desdibujan sobre contenidos e ideas fragmentadas.

En resumen de esta I parte: **Se intentará hallar una relación entre "Potra" y la palabra "Hernia".**

Actualmente en la RAE podemos encontrar las siguientes acepciones de Potra;

1.- Hernia de una víscera u otra parte blanda.
2.- Hernia en el escroto.
3.- Buena suerte.
4.- Partido de fútbol informal y amistoso.

---

Añadir a ello la definición de potro que también considero importante;

1. m. Caballo desde que nace hasta que muda los dientes de leche, que, generalmente, es a los cuatro años y medio de edad.
2. m. Aparato gimnástico formado por cuatro patas y un paralelepípedo forrado de cuero u otro material, sostenido por ellas.
3. m. Máquina de madera que sirve para sujetar los caballos cuando se resisten a dejarse herrar o curar.
4. m. Hoyo que los colmeneros abren en tierra para partir las colmenas.
5. m. Aparato de madera en el cual sentaban a los procesados, para obligarles a declarar por medio del tormento.
6. m. Cosa que molesta y desazona gravemente.
7. m. desuso. Sillón para uso de las parturientas en el acto del alumbramiento.
8. m. antiguo. Orinal de barro.

---

de primer bocado.

1. m. Caballo desde que muda los cuatro dientes llamados palas, que suele ser a los dos años y medio de edad, hasta que muda los cuatro dientes incisivos inmediatos a las palas, lo que suele suceder al cumplir tres años y medio.

~ de segundo bocado.

1. m. Caballo desde que muda los cuatro dientes incisivos inmediatos a las palas, que suele ser a los tres años y medio de edad, hasta que muda los otros cuatro dientes incisivos inmediatos a los colmillos, lo que por lo regular le sucede al cumplir los cuatro años y medio.

---

manda ~s y da pocos.

1. expr. coloq. U. para motejar a quien es largo en prometer y corto en cumplir lo prometido.

□ V. bota de potro

---

Por tanto, "tener potra" con las primeras cuatro acepciones de más arriba indicadas y atendiendo a su origen, podemos decir esencialmente que las ideas relacionadas son enfermedades y la buena suerte. La inclusión dentro de ellas del "partido de futbol", es bastante posterior, y nos da idea de como existen nuevas motivaciones que se van uniendo a la principal, aunque aparentemente no tengan nada que ver.

Como "partido de futbol" no viene definida en los diccionarios más antiguos, siendo una incorporación más actual, que aunque novedosa y conocida por su cercanía, también la tratare para que no se quede en el suspense ó en aquellos que aún desconociendo su procedencia, les agradaría informarse.

Igualmente lo de "Cantarle a uno la potra", es una derivación posterior realizada sobre el dolor que produce la propia hernia y no deja de tener sentido en el tema principal. De esta manera atendiendo a las lenguas en Italiano tenemos "potrè", del verbo poder, ser capaz de, "potra", Futuro imperfecto, ó del mismo Latín "potere", etc...hubiera resultado un rápido recurso y hasta un alivio por tomar un atajo. Así "Potra" como "Ser ó Tener capacidad de predecir ó poder, para que ocurran ciertas cosas".

La verdad, es que también existe otra palabra de origen incierto y que en todo esto parece pasar casi inadvertida, la misma palabra "potra". ¿Es lo mismo potra que potro?. ¿Por qué potra le da nombre a una enfermedad y a la suerte y el potro aparentemente es solo un animal?. ¿Será otra derivación?. ¿Una homonimia? (Coincidencia en la escritura o en la pronunciación de dos palabras que tienen distinto significado y distinta etimología).

Cerca, buscando en otros diccionarios encontré el término "Potroso" que decía así;

Lo que tiene potra, "que todo el mundo que por aquella puerta entrase que fuera torcido ó jorobado ó tenioso ó potroso...cualquiera que tuviera algún defecto corporal...ahora los riñones, o tenia o potroso". En este sentido parece que la "potra" es todo tipo de males y enfermedades.

La voz "potro", "potroso" y "potra" ya aparece recogido en el diccionario de, Antonio Nebrija, Español-Latino, publicado en Salamanca en 1492. Así que la antigüedad y la circulación de estas palabras en el tiempo debe de ser aún anterior.

Me pareció curioso, en un primer vistazo que la palabra "potra", podía relacionarla con "útero", "p-otera-/útero". Las investigaciones al respecto sobre "potra", datos e información en general no es que hayan sido muy abundantes.

No hay que decir que me centre en términos como cirugía, hernia, uretra y muchas voces Griegas y Latinas relacionados con quebrar, salir, bulto, protuberancia, hinchamiento, traspasar..., sin resultado alguno.

Tome y estudie muchas de las definiciones existentes, tipos de hernias, dolencias del vientre y abdomen...*"Una hernia (bulto-salida) es un saco formado por el revestimiento de la cavidad abdominal (peritoneo). El saco pasa a través de un agujero o área débil en la capa fuerte de la pared abdominal que rodea el músculo, denominada fascia".*

[image]

¿Seria "potra" un agujero, una especie de cavidad, un bulto ó abultamiento en el abdomen?. En uno de los libros que trataban sobre la cirugía encontré un apodo que me hizo gracia, referente a los malos cirujanos, "sacapotras". Saca-potras y además en plural. Igual que decimos "Saca-muelas" para un mal dentista, existía también "Saca-potras" para un mal cirujano. ¿Pero que eran las "potras"? Imagine que se referían a las hernias, esos tipos de abultamientos, bultos o sacos. Pensé en el contexto más castizo, "tripas", "salirse las tripas". Pero si alguien opera de hernias. ¿Qué hace que tenga ese sentido peyorativo?

[image]

De hecho pensé en un primer momento en la expresión y relación entre "tripa" y "potra", la verdad es que podría ser una especie de metátesis (*Cambio de lugar de uno o más sonidos dentro de una palabra*), pero en ese momento no le di más importancia. Después apareció y me acerque al conocimiento del término "protrusión", como un desplazamiento patológico ó natural de un órgano o de una parte del cuerpo en especial de las vertebras de la columna.

- El sufijo "sion" procede del grupo "sis" que significa estado irregular, enfermedad.
- El sufijo "cion", corresponderían con do, dor, to, tor, canto, reacción...
- El sufijo "xion" (jo,xo), anexión, anexo, anejo...

Parecería que encajaba con la cuestión de la enfermedad ó el "canto de la potra".

Intente saber un poco más.

La protrusión discal lumbar es una degeneración discal menos importante que la hernia discal. Mientras, la hernia discal puede comprimir alguna de las estructuras del sistema nervioso generando dolores irradiados a los miembros inferiores o superiores. El tamaño de la hernia no tenía relación con los síntomas del paciente.

En este momento, trataba de saber si existía algún tipo de relación dentro de la distinción entre la intensidad en la gravedad, es decir, si la "potra" era igual a la "hernia", quizás la diferencia y su relación se hallaba en su intensidad. La intención era si en los términos, "pro-tru"/ "po-tra", podía observar algún indicador, ya que si el proceso de rotura de las fibras de la zona externa del disco es mayor, se puede producir la expulsión de una parte del núcleo que es lo que se llama hernia discal y obviamente es más grave que el mero desplazamiento.

Aparecía así la voz "protruir", "protruye", "protruya"  del verbo Latino, "protrudĕre", empujar hacia delante. *Dicho de una parte o de un órgano: Desplazarse hacia delante, sobresalir de sus límites normales, de forma natural o patológica*. Así "potra y protru", podrían tener relación dentro de este campo médico, por tanto, también aparecían como alternativas posibles, claro si hubiera sido posible prescindir de la "r" dentro del prefijo "p r o", "protru/potru" - "potru/potra". Pensé en algún tipo de evolución ó simplemente como en aquellos casos abundantes en los que existen una perdida o cambio de fonemas, como problema, poblema ó pobre, probe, forma, foma, gordo, godo, godro...

Aunque interesante, después de analizar los datos, no estaba muy convencido de todo lo averiguado hasta ahora, si bien, me había servido como ayuda para ir visualizando otras conexiones; decidí entonces volver y girar hacia los antiguos diccionarios etimológicos, como el primer diccionario general etimológico de la lengua Española escrito por Roque Bárcia.

Potroso/sa - Adj. Hernioso// Familiar, se dice del que es dichoso y afortunado. Etimología de "potra". Tiene más suerte que un potroso.

Potra - Femenino, familiar. Hernia. Cantarle a uno la potra. Frase metafórica y familiar. Sentir los quebrados algún dolor en la parte lastimada lo que comúnmente sucede en la mudanza de tiempo. // Tener Potra. Frase familiar, ser dichoso. Mi marido tiene una potra y esta que es otra. Frase familiar con que se indica la concurrencia de una doble dificultad ó engorro. Etimología potro como animal ó como tormento.

Nada nuevo. Sin embargo, una palabra que al menos sabemos de su existencia desde el S. XV tendría que aparecer en la literatura clásica de los años y siglos siguientes.

Obviamente, después de buscar mucho, encontré un pasaje en una obra del Siglo de Oro Español del S. XVII de Tirso de Molina "El pretendiente al revés" publicada en el año 1627.

En cursiva el pasaje al que me refiero, aunque también escribo una porción anterior por si pudiera tener una relación general, que desconozco.

---

MENGO:
Mató las mulas un rayo;
no sé cómo vida tengo.
CARMENIO:
¿Las mulas?
MENGO:
Y de camino
el mastín. Dadme otra ropa;
que vengo hecho un palomino.
PEINADO:
¡Qué calado!
MENGO:
Hecho una sopa;
mas dadme algunas en vino,
porque unas sopas con otras
se avengan acá mejor.

*CLORI:

Bien tu enfermedad quillotras.
Lumbre hay.
MENGO:

Vo a entrar en calor.
¡Qué mal tiempo para potras!*

- ¡Qué mal tiempo para potras! /¿ Como que mal tiempo para potras?. ¿y lo de la enfermedad quillotras?. ¿Qué clase de enfermedad es, ó que se refiere?.
- Así, ¿Podría estar relacionado la "hernia", con la enfermedad "Quillotras"?. Ingenuo de mi.

Tenía un objetivo y dos voces con las que iniciar la búsqueda para hallar en primer lugar, su significado y en segundo, la posible relación entre quillotras y potras.

La voz

"Quillotra" aparecía como amante, manceba, enamorados, mujer que con regularidad mantiene relaciones amorosas con una persona con la que no está casada....

"Quillotrar" como verbo, igualmente aparecía con las siguientes entradas.

De quillotro.

1. tr. coloq. Excitar, estimular, avivar.
2. tr. coloq. Cortejar, enamorar a alguien. U. t. c. prnl.
3. tr. coloq. Gustar mucho, cautivar.
4. tr. coloq. Meditar, pensar, estudiar, discurrir.
5. tr. coloq. Componer, engalanar. U. t. c. prnl.
6. prnl. coloq. Quejarse, lamentarse.

---

En cuanto a la palabra "potras", logre encontrar en ese contexto su significado;

*¡Qué mal tiempo para potras!*, significaba ¡Qué mal tiempo para hacer morcillas!.
¿Morcillas?, imagine cualquier tipo de embutido. En Latín: "Botulus-i".

Por fin había encontrado una primera relación entre las palabras "potras" y "hernia". Una hernia es un bulto, como la inguinal, que puede ser doloroso y que ocurre cuando una porción de tejido, como una parte del intestino, (recuérdese tripas), empuja hacia afuera a través de un lugar debilitado en los músculos abdominales y que también se asemeja a la forma de un "Butulus".Imaginemos la forma del embutido de una morcilla, conocida como tripa y la imagen o bulto de la hernia (intestino/tripa).

Así una "hernia" es una "potra", porque de alguna forma y en distintos ámbitos, comparten la palabra "tripa".
Igualmente posee esa forma abombada, redondeada, alargada... como un embutido, figurativamente la hernia, al ser una "tripa" de la que sale una especie de saco asemejando en su abultamiento a la forma de una morcilla (tripa), que a la vez es considerada "tripa".

Ahora cobraba sentido la expresión despectiva vista más arriba, "sacapotras", era como decir "sacamorcillas" ó "sacatripas" en sentido figurado y peyorativo.

Pero esto solo acababa de comenzar, aunque una de las cuestiones importantes, "la hernia", ya estaba averiguada, sin embargo, aún faltaban por responder varias preguntas;

- ¿ Qué pasaba con la enfermedad "Quillotra", estaba relacionado con esto?.
- ¿Si era una enfermedad, estaba relacionada con la ingesta en mal estado de este tipo de productos ó con el botulismo?.
- ¿Era "potra", un potro, ó algún tipo de embutido hecho a base de carne de caballo más joven, que recibía ese nombre y que desconocíamos?.
- ¿Si esta era la relación entre "Potra-Hernia", porque hubo esa vinculación?. ¿Era por los potros?. ¿Por enfermedades en general?.
- ¿Qué relación tienen aquí los potros con la "potra"?. ¿Qué tienen que ver los potros con la suerte?. ¿Existe alguna vinculación?.

(Continuará)

Diego M.

Comment: Tocayo parece que pusiste mucho esfuerzo en esta respuesta, pero ¿de verdad si es necesario un texto tan largo para explicar un término coloquial? Si para entender la expresión uno necesitara conocer tanta información, la expresión ni existiría. Obviamente no he leído esta respuesta, pero la otra (ya aceptada) fue suficiente para mi. Te recomendaría que la edites y dejes solo la información relevante que responda a la pregunta.